# Injection of autowired dependencies Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I know there are several problems like this, but I still cannot figure it out why my example doesn't work.

I have a Spring MVC project in which I have a controller:

```
    @Controller
public class StudentController {

    /** The Constant serialVersionUID. */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(StudentController.class);

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("studentsManager")
    IStudentsManager studentsManager;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("departmentsManager")
    IDepartmentsManager departmentsManager;
...
```

StudentsManager class:

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public class StudentsManager extends JdbcDaoSupport implements IStudentsManager {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("departmentsManager")
    private IDepartmentsManager departmentsManager;
...
```

DepartmentsManager class:

```
    @Transactional
@Repository
public class DepartmentsManager extends JdbcDaoSupport implements
        IDepartmentsManager {

    /** The log. */
    private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(DepartmentsManager.class);

    /** The departments. */
    private List<Department> departments = new ArrayList<Department>();


    public void addDepartment(int id, String name) {
        Department d = new Department(id, name);
        departments.add(d);
    }


    public void addDepartment(Department department)
            throws FileNotFoundException {
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("Entered to add department method  ");
        }
        departments.add(department);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(department.toString()).append(" added");
        log.info(sb.toString());

        this.serialize();
    }

    public Department getDepartment(int departmentId) {
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("Entered to getDepartment");
        }
        for (Department d : departments) {
            if (departmentId == d.getDepartmentId()) {
                return d;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Collection<Department> getAllDepartments() throws SQLException,
            ClassNotFoundException {
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("Entered to getAllDepartments");
        }

        departments.clear();

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        String sql = "SELECT id, name FROM departments ORDER BY id";
        RowMapper<Department> rm = ParameterizedBeanPropertyRowMapper
                .newInstance(Department.class);
        return getJdbcTemplate().query(sql, rm);
    }

    public void serialize() throws FileNotFoundException {
        XStream xstream = new XStream();
        xstream.alias("departments", List.class);
        System.out.println(xstream.toXML(departments));
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("departments.xml", true); 
        xstream.toXML(departments, fos);
    }

    public void deserialize() throws FileNotFoundException {
        XStream xstream = new XStream();
        xstream.alias("departments", List.class);
        departments = (List<Department>) xstream.fromXML(new FileInputStream(
                "departments.xml"));
    }

}
```

The whole context of application:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="amg.net.controller, amg.net.services" />

    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <beans:property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties" />

    <beans:bean id="studentsManager" class="amg.net.services.StudentsManager">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="departmentsManager" class="amg.net.services.DepartmentsManager">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </beans:bean> 

</beans:beans>
```

Stack trace:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'studentController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: amg.net.services.IStudentsManager amg.net.controller.StudentController.studentsManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'studentsManager': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private amg.net.services.IDepartmentsManager amg.net.services.StudentsManager.departmentsManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'departmentsManager' defined in file [/home/praktykant/Documents/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Students/WEB-INF/classes/amg/net/services/DepartmentsManager.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'dataSource' or 'jdbcTemplate' is required
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: amg.net.services.IStudentsManager amg.net.controller.StudentController.studentsManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'studentsManager': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private amg.net.services.IDepartmentsManager amg.net.services.StudentsManager.departmentsManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'departmentsManager' defined in file [/home/praktykant/Documents/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Students/WEB-INF/classes/amg/net/services/DepartmentsManager.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'dataSource' or 'jdbcTemplate' is required
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'studentsManager': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private amg.net.services.IDepartmentsManager amg.net.services.StudentsManager.departmentsManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'departmentsManager' defined in file [/home/praktykant/Documents/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Students/WEB-INF/classes/amg/net/services/DepartmentsManager.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'dataSource' or 'jdbcTemplate' is required
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1017)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private amg.net.services.IDepartmentsManager amg.net.services.StudentsManager.departmentsManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'departmentsManager' defined in file [/home/praktykant/Documents/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Students/WEB-INF/classes/amg/net/services/DepartmentsManager.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'dataSource' or 'jdbcTemplate' is required
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'departmentsManager' defined in file [/home/praktykant/Documents/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Students/WEB-INF/classes/amg/net/services/DepartmentsManager.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'dataSource' or 'jdbcTemplate' is required
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1017)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'dataSource' or 'jdbcTemplate' is required
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.support.JdbcDaoSupport.checkDaoConfig(JdbcDaoSupport.java:112)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DaoSupport.afterPropertiesSet(DaoSupport.java:44)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
    ... 47 more
```

I was always doing it without qualifier and it always worked, but not this time. So i've added this annotations, but still doesn't work.

It looks like component-scan doesnt' work, but I was trying to do some changes with it and it was the same, so I guess the problem is not connected with it.

web.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets 
        and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml,
        /WEB-INF/spring/security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>students</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>students</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>charsetEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>charsetEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
                  org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
                </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: are there any `@Repository` annotations on your Manager classes? If not add it and try aggain.

Comment: I've added @Repository annotations, but still the same

Comment: Are the classes in pagacke `amg.net.controller` or  ` amg.net.services`?

Comment: Well your beans are declared in application context xml so they should be found. It looks like your xml is not correctly processed or not at correct level. How is it declared in your `web.xml` file ?

Comment: in amg.net.controller I have a controller, and in amg.net.services I have the @Repository annotated classes

Comment: What does `root-context.xml` look like?

Comment: I had duplicated context component-scan in the root-context file. Now it's working. Stupid mistake, thanks for help everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You need to annotate the `StudentsManager` and `DepartmentsManager` either with @Component, @Repository or @Service based on what those classes do.

And Also make sure they fall under the packages you are scanning in spring.

Comment: Okey, it solved a bit the problem, but I still have: Error creating bean with name 'departmentsManager': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'dataSource' or 'jdbcTemplate' is required

Comment: need to look at DepartmentsManager class

Comment: The two beans were declared in xml to the should have been found.

Comment: I've edited my post and added full implementation of Departments Manager

Comment: I think that there is a problem with autowiring Departments Manager in Students Manager. I've added @qualifier annotation over there, but did not help.

Comment: Make sure you have annotated StudentsManager as well.

Comment: I have it. Is the implementation of Student Manager bean in xml config correct?